# why plt.tight_layout() failed to tight layout of the last nest_pie chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can someone help me that why `plt.tight_layout` failed to tight the layout of the last nest_pie chart?

> `plt.tight_layout()` has applied to every figure except last one. So strange it seems to me that `plt.show()` can show every figure, but `.tight_layout()` can not tight everyone.

code is here:

def all_pie_nested():

```
for i in a:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    data0 = df.groupby(i)['income'].sum()
    data0.plot.pie(autopct='%.1f%%')
    ax.set(aspect=1)
    for i1 in a:
        if i1 != i:
            size = 0.4

            fig, ax = plt.subplots()

            data1 = df.groupby([i, i1])['income'].sum()
            data0.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1 - size, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
            data1.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
            ax.set(aspect=1)

            for i2 in a:
                if i2 != i1 and i2 != i:
                    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

                    data2 = df.groupby([i, i1, i2])['income'].sum()

                    data0.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1-size, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
                    data1.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
                    data2.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1+size, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
                    ax.set(aspect=1)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the picture below: *Figure_3* & *Figure_5* come from the same code , however, they are different:

[image]

```
for i2 in a:
    if i2 != i1 and i2 != i:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    data2 = df.groupby([i, i1, i2])['income'].sum()

    data0.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1-size, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
    data1.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
    data2.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1+size, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
    ax.set(aspect=1)
```

I've tried to call `plt.tight_layout()`  inside each loop, and set the `figure.autolayout rcParam` to `True` under `for i in a:`, neither of them can make *Figure_5* with same features as
*Figure_3*.

.....................parting line........................

The only sulotion, for the moment, is setting `size` to `0.3` from `0.4`, and `plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True` before `for i in a:

**Hope someone can explain the machanism of it later.**

[image]

```
def all_pie_nested():

    plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True # replace call plt.tight_layout()

    for i in a:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()    

        data0 = df.groupby(i)['income'].sum()
        data0.plot.pie(autopct='%.1f%%')
        ax.set(aspect=1)
        for i1 in a:
            if i1 != i:
                size = 0.3           # change from size = 0.4

                fig, ax = plt.subplots()

                data1 = df.groupby([i, i1])['income'].sum()
                data0.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1 - size, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
                data1.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
                ax.set(aspect=1)

                for i2 in a:
                    if i2 != i1 and i2 != i:
                        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

                        data2 = df.groupby([i, i1, i2])['income'].sum()
                        data0.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1-size, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
                        data1.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
                        data2.plot.pie(ax=ax, radius=1+size, autopct='%.1f%%', wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))
                        ax.set(aspect=1)
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

How many figures do you want ? One or multiple ? If one, why do you call subplots multiple times ? If multiple, you may rather want to call tight_layout() specifically for each figure inside the loops:

```
fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: When you call plt.tight_layout(), I think its result is only applied to the current figure (the last one you created or the last one you modified), hence why not all your figures get adjusted.

Comment: :) thx. again. `plt.tight_layout()` has applied to every figure except last one. So strange it seems to me that `plt.show()` can show every figure, but `.tight_layout()` can not tight everyone.